# Ant build doesn't stop after all Junit tests were executed

Tags: java, ant, junit, batch-processing, build.xml

When I run my build.xml file with ant, somethimes ant is still running ,but all Junit tests were executed.
It says that "test is executing",but junit already stoped.It could be something in background ?

How can I force ant to stop executing after all Junit tests ?

Thanks !

Comment: you should fork you junit test in ant for this reason.

Comment: I know that if if fork junit then when a test will fail,the other test will not be executed.I want to execute all the tests even if a test fails.

Answer (score 0):

issue a kill -3  or "ctrl + \ " to the ant java process which will give you the stacktrace. That will tell you what is your ant actually doing.

Comment: when ant still running ?

Comment: Yes kill -3 <pid of ant>. When the ant is still running after the junit is stopped. When you issue a thread dump at this point, the process omits the backtrace which should be telling you the current state of ant.

Comment: I am runnig on windows,so kill command doesn't work.Do you now something identically from windows ?

Comment: You could also try Ctrl+Break on the ant console.